# Joins on separate columns

Tags: sql-server, join

I am writing a query that is part of a larger data extraction query. The part I am stuck with is best explained as below:

Table1 (T1) columns

- LocationID
- ServiceCategory

Table3 (T3) columns

- LocationID
- ServiceCategory
- ServiceType
- ServiceSequence
- ServiceStatus

Table6 (T6) columns

- LocationID
- ServiceType
- ServiceSequence
- ServiceRate

T1 is the primary table. T3 and T1 are joined using LocationID and ServiceCategory. However, there are possible duplicates for this combination in T3. I am therefore using:

`LEFT JOIN(select distinct T3.LocationID,T3.ServiceCategory from Table3 where ServiceStatus in (2,3,4)) T3`

`ON T1.LocationID=T3.LocationID and T1.ServiceCategory=T3.ServiceCategory`

Of course now I don't have T3.ServiceType to join with Table6. I want to keep the record count from Table1 intact when I eventually get down to a join between T3 and T6. I am using T6.ServiceRate in a further join so it is not particularly important for my question. I am basically getting stuck with the way the tables are designed and how I need to create the joins.

I have a secondary problem where the ServiceCategory in Table3 is shared by two types of ServiceType records. Within a LocationID, I only want one of those ServiceCategory records to be retrieved in my *SELECT* statement. The differentiator is the ServiceType which is either **W** or **I**. The reason I am using a *LEFT JOIN* is because not all T1.LocationID / T1.ServiceCategory records will have a match, so no *INNER JOIN* is possible.

I am looking for some help with these problems. Happy to share some sample data if needed.

Sample Data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding your first issue, are there possible duplicates in T3 on `LocationID`, `ServiceCategory`, and `ServiceType`. If there are no duplicates, then simply add `ServiceType` to your `LEFT JOIN (select distinct ...)` statement. If there are duplicates, then these will be reflected in your result set, and therefore will not retain T1 row count. But isn't this expected behavior? If there are two different `ServiceTypes` for the same `LocId` and `ServiceCategory`, how would the database engine know which `ServiceType` to pick?

Comment: You are correct, up to a point. Using all three columns will result in the same record count. However, there is a scenario where the same LocationID can have two different ServiceType values (W and I) that have the same ServiceCategory. This is the second problem that I am trying to overcome.

Comment: Additionally, something that I forgot in my original note. The ServiceSequence is important. The moment I add it to my *SELECT DISTINCT* my record count goes up. The combination of LocationID, ServiceCategory, ServiceType, and ServiceSequence can result in additional records. How do I eliminate these from the result of my JOIN?

Comment: I fixed it partially by using max(ServiceSequence) over (partition by LocationID, ServiceCategory order by LocationID, ServiceCategory) as maxServiceSeq. This lets me pick only one record if there is a duplicate in the ServiceSequence. I'm still trying to eliminate the situation where two of ServiceType records share the same ServiceCategory. I might have to use a CASE in the SELECT. But I'm not sure how to make it work within a LocationID.

Comment: If you show some sample data and desired results your question will be a whole lot clearer.

Comment: I'm trying to find a good way to share sample data. All the free Markdown/HTML formatting tools look completely mangled when pasted.

Comment: I added screenshots of data snippets from each of the 3 tables. Table 3, where both "I" and "W" records are present for each LocationID is the issue I am trying resolve. As you can see, both have the same ServiceCategory. I do need "I" records for other Locations where there is no duplication between "W" and "I". I'm presently doing the worst possible thing by hard-coding those LocationIDs. It's a timebomb waiting to blow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if I understood right.
You mean that `T3.ServiceType`could be `W` or `I`?

Maybe, you could add a construct with `not EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
T1
LEFT JOIN(select distinct T3.LocationID,T3.ServiceCategory,T3 from Table3 where ServiceStatus in (2,3,4)) T3 
ON T1.LocationID=T3.LocationID and T1.ServiceCategory=T3.ServiceCategory

WHERE
(
T3.ServiceType = 'W' 
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 from Table3 T3n WHERE T3n.ServiceStatus in (2,3,4) and T1.LocationID=T3n.LocationID and T1.ServiceCategory=T3n.ServiceCategory and T3n.ServiceType <> T3.ServiceType)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it eliminates both the *W* and the *I* rows for that particular *LocationID*. I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Hmmmm... Let's think about it once again
Let T3.Servicetype be `I`. This means:
`T3.ServiceType = 'W' ` -> FALSE

Which means, this Subquery has to return sth:

`SELECT TOP 1 1 from Table3 T3n WHERE T3n.ServiceStatus in (2,3,4) and T1.LocationID=T3n.LocationID and T1.ServiceCategory=T3n.ServiceCategory and T3n.ServiceType <> T3.ServiceType`

Maybe you should check further on what this subquery returns?

Comment: Your logic is right. I must have been hasty in placing the WHERE condition earlier today. I took a second look and am getting the results I need. Your suggestion to look at the subquery proved helpful. Problem solved! Thanks a lot for your help!